# How to "unlock" an RwLock?

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex

I'm trying to solve the [thread-ring](https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/threadring-description.html#threadring) problem. In each thread I read the token value

- if it is not mine, check if it's the end of the program

  - if it is then finish the thread
  - otherwise, read again and repeat
- if it is mine (i.e. has my id) then acquire the write lock, increase the value of the token, check if it's the end then tell main thread that I finished it and finish the current thread loop
- If it not over, then release the write lock, and start to read again

There is no unlock. Is there any unlock like the one I need in here?

It seems that I should release the read lock as well, because the write lock won't happen if there is someone reading the data. Is it necessary?

```
fn main() {
    use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};
    use std::thread;
    use std::sync::mpsc::channel;

    const N: usize = 5; //503;
    const STOP_POINT: usize = 100;

    let n = Arc::new(RwLock::new(1));

    let (sender, reciever) = channel();

    for i in 1..N {
        let (n_c, channel) = (n.clone(), sender.clone());
        // println!("Thread n.{} beeing created!", i);

        let a = thread::Builder::new()
            .name(i.to_string())
            .spawn(move || -> () {
                loop {
                    let mut read_only = n_c.read().unwrap();
                    let say_my_name = (*thread::current().name().unwrap()).to_string();

                    // println!("Thread {} says: gonna try!", say_my_name);
                    while (*read_only % N) != i {
                        if *read_only == 0 {
                            break;
                        }
                        // println!("Thread {} says: aint mine!", say_my_name);
                        read_only = n_c.read().unwrap();
                    } // WAIT

                    println!("Thread {} says: my turn!", say_my_name);
                    let mut ref_to_num = n_c.write().unwrap();
                    *ref_to_num += 1;

                    if *ref_to_num == STOP_POINT {
                        channel.send(say_my_name).unwrap();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                ()
            });
        assert_eq!(a.is_ok(), true);
        // thread::spawn();
        // println!("Thread n.{} created!", i);
    }

    println!("{}", reciever.recv().unwrap());
}
```

Answer (score 8):

To release a lock, you let it fall out of scope or explicitly invoke its destructor by calling [`drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.drop.html).

Here's how your program could be written using `drop` in two places:

```
fn main() {
    use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};
    use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
    use std::thread;
    use std::time::Duration;

    const N: usize = 503;
    const STOP_POINT: usize = 100;

    let n = Arc::new(RwLock::new(1));

    let (sender, receiver) = channel();

    for i in 1..N {
        let (n_c, channel) = (n.clone(), sender.clone());
        // println!("Thread n.{} beeing created!", i);

        thread::Builder::new()
            .name(i.to_string())
            .spawn(move || {
                loop {
                    let mut read_only = n_c.read().unwrap();
                    let say_my_name = (*thread::current().name().unwrap()).to_string();

                    // println!("Thread {} says: gonna try!", say_my_name);
                    while (*read_only % N) != i {
                        if *read_only == 0 {
                            break;
                        }

                        drop(read_only); // release the lock before sleeping
                        // println!("Thread {} says: aint mine!", say_my_name);
                        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
                        read_only = n_c.read().unwrap();
                    }

                    println!("Thread {} says: my turn!", say_my_name);
                    drop(read_only); // release the read lock before taking a write lock
                    let mut ref_to_num = n_c.write().unwrap();
                    *ref_to_num += 1;

                    if *ref_to_num == STOP_POINT {
                        channel.send(say_my_name).unwrap();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            })
            .expect("failed to spawn a thread");
        // println!("Thread n.{} created!", i);
    }

    println!("{}", receiver.recv().unwrap());
}
```

Note that if we don't reassign `read_lock` in the `while` loop, the compiler will give an error because `read_lock` doesn't hold a valid value after we call `drop(read_lock)`. Rust is fine with local variables that are temporarily uninitialized, but of course we need to reinitialize them before we can use them again.

Here's how the thread's main loop could be written to use a scope to replace one of the `drop`s:

```
loop {
    let say_my_name = (*thread::current().name().unwrap()).to_string();
    {
        let mut read_only = n_c.read().unwrap();

        // println!("Thread {} says: gonna try!", say_my_name);
        while (*read_only % N) != i {
            if *read_only == 0 {
                break;
            }

            drop(read_only);
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
            // println!("Thread {} says: aint mine!", say_my_name);
            read_only = n_c.read().unwrap();
        }

        println!("Thread {} says: my turn!", say_my_name);
    } // read_only is dropped here

    let mut ref_to_num = n_c.write().unwrap();
    *ref_to_num += 1;

    if *ref_to_num == STOP_POINT {
        channel.send(say_my_name).unwrap();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I kinda understood that if the if a lock fall out of scope, then it is released, but I could figure it out how to make it happen to the write lock.
The drop is just what I need.