# How can I release a std::io::StdinLock externally?

Tags: rust

I'm looking for a way for release [`std::io::StdinLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.lock) externally.

In the following case, two threads are spawned (not counting the main thread) named `read_stdin` and `ttl`.

- `read_stdin` is locked by `handle.read_line` and waits for `read_line` to free itself.
- `ttl` waits 2 seconds to free itself.

Is there a way to release `read_stdin` when `ttl` is released?

```rust
use std::io;
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let read_stdin = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut buffer = String::new();
        let stdin = io::stdin();
        let mut handle = stdin.lock();
        handle.read_line(&mut buffer).unwrap();
        println!("{}", buffer);
    });

    let ttl = thread::spawn(move || {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
        println!("end");
    });

    ttl.join();
    read_stdin.join();
}
```

Comment: The lock is released when the lock guard goes out of scope. See [How to “unlock” an RwLock?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47916718/155423)

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [What is the standard way to get a Rust thread out of blocking operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52465480/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: you don't that the very specific point of having lock

Comment: Thanks @Stargateur for your answer, it resolve my issue.